# Book & Writer data for commercial use (goodreads contradictory behaviour)

Tags: licensing, commercial, creative-commons, non-commercial, open-data

I am working on small app for searching authors and their works. I had quite issues with finding reasonable and clean data. Main problem was a licence of usage and since I plan to use data for affiliate marketing (commercial-use), most data sources were pretty much out of question.

I really liked worldcat data. But on worldcat website is clearly stated ([worldcat terms&conditions](https://www.oclc.org/content/dam/ext-ref/worldcat-org/terms.html)) that data must be used Non-Commercially. After some research, it seems that only possible data I can use (and **keep**) for commercial usage must be published under **Creative Commons** and worldcat data certainly are not.

However, on wikipedia ([goodreads page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodreads#Catalog_data)) is stated that in 2012 goodreads imported worldcat data, which is also supported on goodreads announcement ([goodreads announcement](https://www.goodreads.com/topic/show/766331-announcement-goodreads-to-import-worldcat-library-of-congress-data-to)) where obviously one of the user (1. comment) also raises doubts about legal (copyright) issues.

It is quite obvious that goodreads is not non-profitable website and uses the data for profit.

**How could this be?**